# jQuery Flip with multiple audio files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio

I have a div with two sides. The front has 14 questions on it, all linked to a script which flips the card when the questions are clicked. On the flip side are some html5 audio controls. I have 14 clips I'd like to link to each question, but as of now, I only know how to link one. I'm new to coding and have my html/css pretty down, but am only starting js now. Like last week now. So, please forgive what I'm sure is a simple question. I'm wondering whether there's a way to load each separate audio file depending on which question has been clicked. So if the user clicks question 1, the card flips and mp3-1 is loaded, but if they click question 7, the card flips and mp3-7 is loaded. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

```
<div id="card">

  <div class="front">
    <button class="buttons audioClick1 play flipMe"></button>
    <button class="buttons audioClick2 flipMe"></button>
    <button class="buttons audioClick3 flipMe"></button>
    <button class="buttons audioClick4 flipMe"></button>
    <button class="buttons audioClick5 flipMe"></button>
    <button class="buttons audioClick6 flipMe"></button>
    <button class="buttons audioClick7 flipMe"></button>
    <button class="buttons audioClick8 flipMe"></button>
    <button class="buttons audioClick9 flipMe"></button>
    <button class="buttons audioClick10 flipMe"></button>
    <button class="buttons audioClick11 flipMe"></button>
    <button class="buttons audioClick12 flipMe"></button>
    <button class="buttons audioClick13 flipMe"></button>
    <button class="buttons audioClick14 flipMe"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="back">
    <audio class="controls" id="myTune" src="audio/clipOne.mp3"></audio>
    <button class="playClip buttonStyle" onclick="document.getElementById('myTune').play()"><img class="svg" src="images/play128.svg" alt="Play Button"></button>
    <button class="pauseClip buttonStyle" onclick="document.getElementById('myTune').pause()"><img class="svg" src="images/pause18.svg" alt="pause button"></button>
    <button class="stopClip buttonStyle" onclick="document.getElementById('myTune').pause(); document.getElementById('myTune').currentTime = 0;"><img class="svg" src="images/media26.svg" alt="Stop Button"></button>
    <button class="flipMe btnMove"></button>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  $('#card').flip({
    trigger: 'manual'
  })
  $('.flipMe').on('click', function() {
    $('#card').flip('toggle');
  });

</script>
<style>
  //css
  #card {
    width: 58%;
    height: 58%;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    // border: 1px solid white;
  }

  .front,
  .back {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
  }

  .front {
    background-image: url(images/frontCard.jpg);
  }

  .back {
    background-image: url(images/backCard.jpg);
  }

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't do the entire thing for you but this should give you some idea. It's a working example

**HTML**

```
<div id="card">

  <div class="front">
    <button class="buttons audioClick1 flipMe">1</button>
    <button class="buttons audioClick2 flipMe">2</button>
    <button class="buttons audioClick3 flipMe">3</button>

  </div>
  <div class="back">



  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {

    $('#card').flip({
        trigger: 'manual'
    });



    $("button").on("click", function() {
        var mp3Number = $(this).text();
        alert(mp3Number)
        $(".back").append("<audio controls src=" + "/mp3-" + mp3Number + "></audio>")

    });

    $('.flipMe').on('click', function() {
        $('#card').flip('toggle');

    });

});
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but with this code the page loads only the back side of the div, rather than the front where the buttons actually are.

Comment: Like I said, I didn't do the entire thing for you but it should give you an idea